# Popup in Xamarin is too long

Tags: c#, xamarin, popup

I tried to create a popup in Xamarin forms using Xamarin.Community.Toolkit. But unexpectedly Popup is too long and like vertically full-screen like this.
[My Screenshot][1]
How can I fix it.
My UI code is below.

````
<xct:Popup 
            xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
             x:Class="Barcode_Mobile.Views.ConnectionPage" >
    
<Grid  Padding="20,10,20,10" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Text="Server And Database Informations"
                   FontSize="18"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="Start" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <Entry  Placeholder="Example: 127.0.0.1"  Grid.Row="1" x:Name="TxtServerAddress"/>          
            <Entry  Placeholder="Username"  Grid.Row="2" x:Name="TxtLogIn"/>
            <Entry  Placeholder="Password"  Grid.Row="3" x:Name="TxtPasswd" IsPassword="True"/>
            <Picker Grid.Row=" 4" x:Name="DbPicker"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" Visual="Material"/>
            <Button Text="Connect" Grid.Row="5" x:Name="BtnConnect" Clicked="BtnConnect_Clicked" WidthRequest="300"/>
        </Grid>               
 </xct:Popup>```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dmdca.jpg
````

Comment: The popup has [vertical and horizontal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/popup#properties) layout properties. Try setting VerticalOptions to Start or Center

Comment: I tried like this. But still not working.

Comment: Refere to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71227684/how-to-set-size-of-xamarin-community-toolkit-popup-to-wrap-content-dynamically-i/77898052#77898052

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set size of Xamarin Community Toolkit Popup to wrap content dynamically in Xamarin Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71227684/how-to-set-size-of-xamarin-community-toolkit-popup-to-wrap-content-dynamically-i)

Answer (score 4):

Finally I fixed it! I added a `size` line in the `xct:Popup` tag like this:

```xml
<xct:Popup
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
    x:Class="Barcode_Mobile.Views.ConnectionPage"
    size="300,320">
```