# How to set size of Xamarin Community Toolkit Popup to wrap content dynamically in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-community-toolkit

I have a **Xamarin.CommunityToolkit - Popup**. I don't want to predefine its size. I want it to size according to the content dynamically. Is there any way to achieve this?

**Here is my XAML code:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xct:Popup xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
           xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
           x:Class="SampleProject.Views.SamplePopup">

    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Hello Xamarin.Forms!" />
        <Button Text="Close Popup" Clicked="ClosePopup" />
    </StackLayout>
</xct:Popup>
```

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/937

Answer (score 2):

The current implementation doesn't support such feature, as Amjad mentioned in his comment there was a similar [feature request](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/937) in the past but it was closed as things were migrating to the new repo .NET MAUI community toolkit.

If you are interested you can open a [discussion](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/discussions/) explaining or pointing to the link of that feature request.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is an existing bug report for the community toolkit popup dynamic auto-height adjustment issue, you may consider a workaround by dynamically setting the popup height based on its content.

```
<xct:Popup
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
    x:Class="SampleXamarinForms.SamplePopup"
    SizeChanged="Popup_SizeChanged"
    x:Name="myPopup">
    <StackLayout
        x:Name="myStacklayout">
        <Label Text="Hello Xamarin.Forms!" />
        <Button Text="Close Popup" Clicked="ClosePopup" />
    </StackLayout>
</xct:Popup>
```

---

```
public partial class SamplePopup : Popup
    {        
        public SamplePopup ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        void Popup_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double width = GetDeviceWidth() - 40;
            double height = myStacklayout.Height;
            myPopup.Size = new Size(width, height);
        }

        private double GetDeviceWidth()
        {
            var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
            var width = mainDisplayInfo.Width;
            return width;
        }
    }
```