# Make popup size to be always equal to the size of its content

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-maui, maui-community-toolkit

I wonder if it's possible to make [community toolkit popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup) size to get automatically set to the size of it's content? For example it contains a listview that is bound to the list of items. If I add new item in design time (not runtime) I can open the popup code-behind and make the popup longer like `Size = new(200, 300);` -> `Size = new(200, 350);`, but better if popup was smart enough to extend its size automatically right to size of it's content.

Just in case to clarify again: talking only about static content, its size does not change in runtime, but can do lots of experimentations with styling in design time, and do not want to update popup size each time along with it. Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/937 you can open a similar issue in communitytoolkit Maui repo

Comment: As far as I know thats not possible yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set size of Xamarin Community Toolkit Popup to wrap content dynamically in Xamarin Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71227684/how-to-set-size-of-xamarin-community-toolkit-popup-to-wrap-content-dynamically-i)

Comment: well, right if it's not yet implemented, it's also an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I Found a way to solve this problem and it is working for me. (.NET MAUI):

In **SamplePopup.xaml** for Popup:

```
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
               xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
               Color="Transparent" 
               x:Class="SampleApp.SamplePopup">
    <Grid>
        <Frame VerticalOptions="Center">
            ...
        </Frame>
    </Grid>
</toolkit:Popup>
```

Use `Grid` for Primary Structure,
 And `VerticalOptions` of Secondary
Element set to `Center`.
 And, Of course, The Color of Popup set to Transparent.

Comment: finally!! and just in time! this works great! nice job and thanks for sharing!